# SharePoint 2013 Foundation: Get Current Logged-in User's AD Profile Properties

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I am having SharePoint 2013 Foundation. I want to retrieve current logged-in user's profile properties from AD. As there is no User Profile Service in SharePoint 2013 Foundation, is there some workaround to retrieve profile properties of a current logged-in user, who is an AD user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use below code to retrieve current logged-in user's profile details from Active Directory in SharePoint 2013 Foundation.

```
string userLogin = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
                // To get the right context, run with elevated privileges  
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
                    var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.IdentityType.SamAccountName, userLogin);

                    lblName.Text = userPrincipal.Name;

                    if (userPrincipal != null)
                    {
                        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = userPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                        lblPhoneNumber.Text = directoryEntry.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value.ToString();                        
                        lblDepartment.Text = directoryEntry.Properties["department"].Value.ToString();
                        lblCompany.Text = directoryEntry.Properties["company"].Value.ToString();                            
                        //You can pull required details from active directory.
                    }

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind to do it programmably you can use is JavaScript object model -
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj920104.aspx

or

You can use it REST API - 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31210.sharepoint-2013-get-user-details-from-person-or-group-field-using-rest-api.aspx

Hope this is help somehow

Comment: I can't use JSOM as it is SharePoint Foundation 2013.